# Unable to launch a browser using Selenium and WebDriver

Tags: java, windows, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've reverted some of my JAR files in order to be able to import the webdrivers within Eclipse (WebDriver, Chromdriver, GeckoDriver)...

I was successful in importing said drivers but am unable to actually launch the browsers associated with them.

My code is:

```
package webElementsandDrivers;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class wDrivers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\munta\\WebDrivers\\chromedriver");    
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting in the Eclipse console reads:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.<init>(DriverService.java:259)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.<init>(ChromeDriverService.java:101)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:94)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:123)
    at webElementsandDrivers.wDrivers.main(wDrivers.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 5 more
```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You were pretty close. As you are on [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) [os](/questions/tagged/os) along with the executable binary i.e. *`chromedriver`* you also need to pass the extension i.e. *`exe`*.

Effectively, your line of code will be:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\munta\\WebDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've added the .exe to my line of code but am still receiving the same error(s) unfortunately... :/

Answer (score 0):

You might be struggling over different versions.

Example: Your Project startet 2 weeks ago. So you have used chrom-driver Version 101.xxx.
In the last days chrom-Browser got an update and is now version 103.xxx.

Your driver will not start with this combination. That was a point last days here on my side.

Please check your driver Version and Browser Version.